# Adding an additional field to login with AWD Facebook Wordpress Plugin

Tags: facebook, wordpress

I am using [AWD Facebook](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/facebook-awd/) wordpress plugin to allow my visitors to login with their Facebook account information. When a visitor registers on my site I automatically create a new post that is titled with their username and includes their Facebook profile picture as the content. The code for that is below:

```
function my_create_page($user_id){
$fbuide = 0;
$the_user = get_userdata($user_id);
$new_user_name = $the_user->user_login;
$new_user_avatar = get_avatar($the_user->user_email);

global $AWD_facebook;
$fbuide = $AWD_facebook->uid;

$headers = get_headers('http://graph.facebook.com/' . $fbuide . '/picture?type=large',1);

    if(isset($headers['Location'])) {
        $url = $headers['Location']; // string
    } else {
        $url = false; 
    }

$my_avatar = "<img src='" . $url . "' class='avatar AWD_fbavatar' alt='" . $alt . "' height='" . $size . "' />";
    $my_post = array();
    $my_post['post_title'] = $new_user_name;
    $my_post['post_type'] = 'post';
    $my_post['post_content'] =  $my_avatar;
    $my_post['post_status'] = 'publish';
    wp_insert_post( $my_post );
}
add_action('user_register', 'my_create_page');
```

What I am looking to accomplish is a bit different though. I also want to include a brief biography about the user (currently the post is simply their picture). So when a visitor logs in with AWD Facebook, their needs to be an additional field that allows the user to type in their bio. Then I would be able to grab that info from their user profile and include it in the post. Any ideas on how I can accomplish this? Is there a different way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend storing their Facebook picture as metadata and use the content area as their bio for the automatically generated post. So something like this should get you started:

```
$my_post = array(
    'post_title'=>$new_user_name,
    'post_type'=>'post',
    'post_content'=>'',
    'post_status'=>'publish'
);
if( $id = wp_insert_post( $my_post ) ){
    update_post_meta($id, 'avatar', $url);
}
```

Then you can generate the loop like so:

```
if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    //... stuff here
    $avatar = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'avatar', 'true');
    the_content();
    echo '<img class="avatar AWD_fbavatar" src="'.$avatar.'" alt="'.$alt.'" height="'.$size.'" />';
endwhile;endif;
```

Comment: What you need to make sure of is that if the user is not registered, you provide them with some kind of front-end UI to send their bio information as POST data to update the post. Otherwise, you need to give the newly registered user permission to update the post's content.